# How to change dialog fragment size in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am using a Dialog fragment to show a dialog. However, my dialog does not show in the favorite size and it is very small. I set the size with "match_parent", but it does not show as well as I want.

Dialog xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="لطفا وارد حساب کاربری خود شوید"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_loginDialog_email"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:hint="پست الکترونیک"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/edt_loginDialog_pass"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="پست الکترونیک"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="فراموشی رمز عبور"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_vpn_key_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_loginDialog_signup"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_signup_style"
            android:text="ثبت نام"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_loginDialog_login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_call_style"
            android:text="ورود"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and it is my dialog fragment code that show how I Implement it

```
public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_dialog,container,false);
        Button btnLogin=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_loginDialog_login);
        Button btnSignup=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_loginDialog_signup);
        EditText edtEmail=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_loginDialog_email);
        EditText edtPass=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_loginDialog_pass);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my dialog picture link:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your activity code where you inflate your dialog fragment ?

Comment: I post my dialog fragment here

Answer (score 1):

If you want set the dialog size in xml try this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="<desire size>"
          android:layout_height="<desire size>">

          ....
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

but My weapon of choice, set the size programmatically.

- Percentage size:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        int dialogWidth = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.9f);
        int dialogHeight = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.8f);
        if (getDialog().getWindow() == null) return;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    }
```

- Dp size:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Reference to dimens.xml 
        //<dimen name="dialog_with">200dp</dimen>
        //<dimen name="dialog_height">200dp</dimen>
        int dialogWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_width);
        int dialogHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_height);
        if (getDialog().getWindow() == null) return;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in onStart() of your dialogFragment

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: what you mean by dialog here?

Comment: It's a `Dialog` instance, before you show the fragment you just do `Dialog dialog = loginDialog.getDialog();`